# MySQL 1064 Error what is the way around solving the syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I needed some help because im a beginner in MYSQL I have tried to look at other posts for this error have gotten nowhere.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT max(count) from (Select activity, count(*) from FRIENDS group by activity' at line 7

Why is this error being generated and how do i fix this?

```sql
SELECT activity
FROM (SELECT activity, count(*) FROM FRIENDS GROUP BY activity) AS getActivities
WHERE count NOT IN (
    SELECT min(count)
        FROM (SELECT activity, count(*) FROM FRIENDS GROUP BY activity ) AS maximum,
    SELECT max(count)
        FROM (SELECT activity, count(*) FROM FRIENDS GROUP BY activity) AS minimum
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select activity
from (Select activity, count(*)
      from FRIENDS
      group by activity
     ) as getActivities
where count not in (Select min(count) from (Select activity, count(*) from FRIENDS group by activity ) as maximum,
                    SELECT max(count) from (Select activity, count(*) from FRIENDS group by activity) as minimum
                   );
```

You have multiple errors.  For instance:

- `count(*)` has no column alias.  But it needs a name because it is in a subquery.
- The subquery has no table alias.
- The subqueries in the outer `where` have parentheses.
- The `,` implies that you intend the subqueries as scalar subqueries, but they can return multiple rows.

I think you intend:

```
select f.activity
from friends f
group by f.activity
having count(*) > (select count(*)
                   from friends f2
                   group by f2.activity
                   order by count(*) asc
                   limit 1
                  ) and
       count(*) < (select count(*)
                   from friends f2
                   group by f2.activity
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the step by step explanation! I will study this when i create subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your sql string:

- Not alias count(*) column
- No group 2 table in a condition not in

Let try this query :

```
SELECT activity 
FROM ( SELECT activity, COUNT(*) AS Number FROM FRIENDS GROUP BY activity) AS getActivities
WHERE Number NOT IN (SELECT MIN(Number) FROM (SELECT activity, COUNT(*) AS Number FROM FRIENDS GROUP BY activity )  AS maximum)
AND Number NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Number) FROM (SELECT activity, COUNT(*) AS Number FROM FRIENDS GROUP BY activity) AS minimum)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to Fix.

```
select activity from ( Select activity, count(*) as count from FRIENDS group by activity) as getActivities
     where count not in  
 (
   Select min(count) as count from (Select activity, count(*) from FRIENDS group by activity ) as maximum
   union all
   SELECT max(count) as count from (Select activity, count(*) from FRIENDS group by activity) as minimum
 )
```